# Result set not updatable

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm doing an statement with:

```
Statement statement = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
try(ResultSet results = statement.executeQuery(String.format("SELECT id, id2 FROM SETTINGS WHERE instance3 = %s, instance.getId())));
```

But I get this:

> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.NotUpdatable: Result set not updatable (referenced table has no primary keys). This result set must comd from a statement that was created with a result set type of ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE, the query must select one table, can not use functions and must select all primary keys from that table.

Any ideas why is this happening?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22271475/jdbc-deleting-an-entry-primary-keys-concur-updatable-issues

Comment: Why are you using `String.format` for setting parameter values? It is unsafe and opens you to SQL injection.

Comment: The exception message is pretty clear, the table you selected has no primary key (or you did not select all primary key columns). Please include all relevant DDL in your question.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel exactly . same thing discussed here :https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=8527

Comment: I dont get it, is the only error which is throwing.

Answer (score -1):

You are creating a statement that allows the result set to be updatable. A default `ResultSet` object is not updatable, and has a cursor that moves forward only. So you need to use the following code fragment, in which `con` is a valid `Connection` object. It illustrates how to make a result set that is scrollable and insensitive to updates by others, and that is updatable.

from : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html

you can more refer from above source document link.

```
PreparedStatement prepStmt= conn.prepareStatement(query,
    ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
```

Comment: Have you actually read the question, the create statement has the same properties: `createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE)`